# How the Saptrishis are Identified for all Manvantaras?

Tags: manvantara, saptarshi

Who/how are the Saptrishis & Manus in Hindu mythology identified for all the 14 Manvantaras? According to a article on Wikipedia the names of the Saptrishis for all the 14 Manvantaras are already identified well ahead of time/period. My question is how the names are given prior w.r.t Manvantara (which is a very huge timelime.)

Please advise.